# MySql select query to filter out record if field has multuple NULL entries for same SN

Tags: mysql

I have a master item ship/return table where we keep track of every SN shipped (date it was shipped, where it was shipped to, and if the SN was returned).  We have some records that show a SN was shipped, then shipped again without the previous return info. This is because someone entered the SN as shipped when it actually was not shipped. I need to write a MySQL query that will show all shipped SN’s but not include the record without the return data when it was shipped after.

Here is an example of the data from my query:

```
Select * From database1.Deployed_Returned group by SN, RMA_No ORDER BY SN, Date_Shipped;
```

| SN | Date_Shipped | Ship_to_Store | Date_Received | Received_from_Store | RMA_No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 4/28/2021 | LA_7146 | 6/9/2021 | LA_7146 | 12356 |
| 1111 | 6/22/2021 | Denver_2114 | 8/18/2021 | Denver_2114 | 12557 |
| 1111 | 8/20/2021 | NY_7890 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1111 | 9/29/2021 | Miami_9821 | 11/30/2022 | Miami_9821 | 13029 |
| 1111 | 12/5/2022 | Atlanta_1278 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2222 | 5/12/2022 | Chicago_3476 | 11/24/2022 | Chicago_3476 | 12987 |
| 2222 | 12/5/2022 | Denver_2114 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3333 | 1/20/2023 | LA_7146 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

SN: 1111, Date_Shipped: 8/20/2021, Date_Received: NULL.  This record needs to be removed (because the next record shows it shipped on 9/29/2022)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0 you can use CTE - [13.2.20 WITH Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

So, at the first step you find maximal `Date_Shipped` for each `SN` which is the date of latest shipped and not returned item.

Then you find records for each item where `Date_Received` is `NULL` but `Date_Shipped` is less then maximal value for found item.

```sql
WITH
    last_shipments AS (
        SELECT MAX(Date_Shipped) AS Date_Shipped, SN
        FROM Deployed_Returned
        GROUP BY SN
    )
SELECT * FROM Deployed_Returned AS d
    JOIN last_shipments AS l ON d.SN = l.SN;
    WHERE d.Date_Received = NULL AND d.Date_Shipped < l.Date_Shipped
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a
[self join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Self-join).

To begin, create a temp reporting table that will simplify your life:

```
CREATE TABLE returned AS
SELECT *
FROM database1.Deployed_Returned
GROUP BY  SN, RMA_No ORDER
```

Giving it a proper index wouldn't hurt, either.
Sometimes CREATE TABLE ... followed by INSERT INTO ...
is the most convenient way to arrange that.

Now identify bogus records according to your business logic.
The OP did not explain exactly what that is.
Here is one take on it.
Possibly `RMA_No` should also be involved.

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM returned r1
JOIN returned r2  ON r1.SN = r2.SN
WHERE r1.Date_Received IS NULL
  AND r2.Date_Received IS NOT NULL
```

You may also find it helpful to display selected `r2` details
such as the date received.

Verify the business logic, and then
use those result rows to DELETE rows that are bogus.
You may find it helpful to add an `is_bogus` boolean
column, so you can try some UPDATE commands and
then finally when you're confident of the result do a
DELETE ... WHERE is_bogus;